# Order of a finite sum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, functions

How to prove that the order of 
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} k^{-d/2 + 1} e^{-\frac{n}{k}}
$$
is $O(n^\frac{4-d}{2})$?

I would like to bound the sum by integral, but the function is not monotonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monotonicity does not matter so much. We have that
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{1-d/2}e^{-n/k} $$
is a Riemann sum associated with the integral:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} x^{1-d/2}e^{-1/x}\,dx = \int_{1}^{+\infty}z^{d/2-3}e^{-z}\,dz =\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}-2,1\right)$$
that gives a value for the incomplete $\Gamma$ function. It follows that:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}k^{1-d/2}e^{-n/k} \approx n^{2-\frac{d}{2}}\cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}-2,1\right)$$
as $n\to +\infty$.